# Change the order of rows of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, sql-server-2012

I need to change the order of rows of a table. I kinda managed it by deleting the whole table and insert the rows in the correct order, but there are a few problems. First of all here's my script:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Leistungsfaehigkeit]
       ([FK_ID_Ref]
       ,[FK_ID_Lie]
       ,[Frage]
       ,[Status]
       ,[DokumentVorhanden]
       ,[Dokument]
       ,[InsertUser]
       ,[InsertDate]
       ,[UpdateUser]
       ,[UpdateDate])
 SELECT [FK_ID_Ref]
       ,[FK_ID_Lie]
       ,ar.[Frage]
       ,a.[Status]
       ,a.[DokumentVorhanden]
       ,a.[Dokument]
       ,[InsertUser]
       ,[InsertDate]
       ,[UpdateUser]
       ,[UpdateDate] FROM Leistungsfaehigkeit as a
       INNER JOIN Leistungsfaehigkeit_Ref as ar ON
        a.FK_ID_Ref = ar.ID

ORDER BY FK_ID_Lie, FK_ID_Ref

DELETE FROM Leistungsfaehigkeit
   WHERE ID <= 504
```

The problem is that the column `[Frage]` is sorted in an incorrect order and I need to sort it correctly now. As I said, with this script `[Frage]` is sorted correctly but the columns `[Status], [DokumentVorhanden], [Dokument]` won't get sorted. They just stay in the same position where they are now. In other words: They don't change their position / "sort order" like `[Frage]` does.

If I didn't explain it clearly enough and you got any questions, just ask. I hope you can help me.

EDIT 1:

By reading the comments I should add a example with some data. At the moment the table looks like this:

[image]

After I ran the script the table changes to this:

[image]

This is what I meant with "`[Frage]` changes his sort order while `[Status], [DokumentVorhanden], [Dokument]` don't.".

I just don't understand why `[Status], [DokumentVorhanden], [Dokument]` won't get sorted like `[Frage]`.

Comment: Table data is stored unordered. (You can specify ORDER BY when you SELECT data.)

Comment: You don't need to delete anything to get an order since a table has no inherent order, you just need the correct `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Your terminology is also very mixed up.  You was that the ***row*** `[Frage]` is sorted.  But `[Frage]` is a *column* or a *field*, not a *row*.  And then you say that "the ***rows*** [Status], [DokumentVorhanden], [Dokument] won't get sorted", these are also fields.  Assuming you mean you want the rows sorted by the values in those fields, how do you propose to have the data sorted by different fields?  I strongly suggest you include some example data, because it sounds like you're asking the impossible.

Comment: At any furhther SELECT sql server is free to return rows in any order, if no explicit ORDER BY is specified. No index, no other table features guarantee the order of rows in the result set but explicit ORDER BY.

Comment: @MichaelFreundorfer, it is simply because a table must be treated as an unordered set of rows.  The only way to provide deterministic ordering is to specify `ORDER BY` in the query when selecting from the table.  This is regardless of indexes on the underlying table.  See http://www.dbdelta.com/order-by-is-required/.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - a clustered index does nothing in terms of guaranteeing the order in which rows are returned by queries. As others have said, the only thing that does guarantee row order is the `ORDER BY` applied to the particular `SELECT` query that is pulling data out of the table.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yeah, just had a look over the documentation again: "The only time the data rows in a table are stored in sorted order is when the table contains a clustered index." Which indeed, has no influence over how data is retrieved and displayed. So, you **need** a `ORDER BY` to guarantee a specific order, when retrieving data.

Comment: Do you have Clustered Index or Non-Clustered index on this table? What you mean my sorting here?

Comment: Can you provide a result set of what you're receiving, and what you want to be the result set ?  Because there is a basic misunderstanding here of ordering records in the storage (clustered index), and ordering them in the queries (indexes and order-by clauses).